# Concurrent algorithm for strongly connected components (SCCs)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, concurrency, bigdata

Is anybody aware of a concurrent version of Tarjan's SCCs algorithm, Kosaraju's algorithm or any other fast, O(|V| + |E|) algorithm for finding SCCs? Neither of those algorithms seem to be very hard to multithread, but I'd be happy for somebody else to have done this job.
What I'm trying to handle here is an 8 GB directed graph, which I keep in RAM using a big AWS instance, and I'd like to make a good use of all 16 cores.

Comment: I do not believe this question shows no understanding of the problem. After a full day of research into this topic I have got a bunch of hardcore scientific papers and no concrete piece of code. The topic is niche and information is scarce, but I'm doing my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possibly the best paper I have found so far, I'll have a go at the implementation. http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/1e4115aea78b6e7c85256b360066f0d4/d8e3597a4172437b8525709f006e42b0?OpenDocument